# Задать все значения анимации в одну строчку

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```
animation-name: bell-ring;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
animation-delay: -1.5s;
animation-direction: alternate;
transform-origin: 50%;
```

Как задать все значения в одну строчку, то есть не разбивать по отдельности...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Comment: У меня не выходит...

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте пример, как Вы пытаетесь записать свойство.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легко и просто:

```css
.bell1 {
  animation-name: bell-ring;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-delay: -1.5s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  transform-origin: 50%;
}

.bell2 {
  animation: bell-ring 1s ease-in-out -1.5s infinite alternate;
  transform-origin: 50%;
}

@keyframes bell-ring {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    background: blue
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bell1">123</div>
<div class="bell2">123</div>
```

Если исходить [из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81), то очерёдность должна выглядеть так:

```
animation: duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction name;
```

Но я обычно делаю так:

```
animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode;
```

Перевод на русский:

```
animation: название продолжительность временнáя-функция задержка количество-итераций направление режим-заполнения;
```